# When I use Laravel JWT this line appears in route class but I cant determine the error

Tags: php, laravel

Below code in **route class**

```
Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->group(function(Request $request) {
   Route::resource('book','/API/BookController');
});
```

This is the error

> Argument 1 passed to `Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}()` must be an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`, an instance of
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Request` type hint and parameter:

```
Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('book','/API/BookController');
});
```